# C# Wait delegate finish before continue

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, datagridview, delegates

I need to access a DataGridView control from a a thread other than the thread it was created on. I read I must use a delegate and it works, but I need to wait that delegate finishes before continue in the thread. I tried to call `EndInvoke` after `BeginInvoke`, but the thread continues.

```
public void ArrangeGrid()
{
    ArrangeGridHandler ag = ArrangeGridAsync;
    IAsyncResult result = ag.BeginInvoke(cb, null);
    ag.EndInvoke(result);
}
```

When I call `ArrangeGrid()` the thread continues even if it isn't finished.  How can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Delegate.BeginInvoke doesn't invoke it on your gui thread. Try `Control/Form.Invoke(...);`. That'll execute it on the correct thread as well as wait for completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using an Async method a new thread will be created for you.

Try to use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 public void ArrangeGrid()
    {          
         if(this.InvokeRequired) 
          { 
             Action  arrange = ArrangeGrid ;  
               this.Invoke(arrange); 
          }
          else
          {  
            //insert your code here  
          }
    }
```

Comment: It works only if I execute step by step, else the thread seems not wait `ArrangeGrid` complete.

Comment: It works, there was another method called before which had the same problem. Thank you!